# how to access variable of one method from another method within the same class in django class based views

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I need to access the value of method variable from another method in django class based views. I have defined a variable as none in class variable. I have created two method inside the django class as like below

```
 class XXXXX(UpdateView):
    y = None

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        y = 10
        return super(xxxxx,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        # Here i want to access the value of variable y which is in get_context_data method
        # i have tried to access like **self.y**. But am getting the value as **None**
```

Can anyone help me to find what mistake i did

Comment: I have tried as you said. but it's not working

Comment: Are you sure, that `get_context_data()` is called BEFORE `post()`? If I remember correctly it's called, when you render template.

Comment: The variable `y` in `get_context_data` is not the same as the class property `y`. Since `y = None` you're getting that value. The suggestion by @devoto13 is correct. You have to change the first line of `get_context_data` according to his comment.

Comment: Yes, get_context_data() is called BEFORE post(). I tried to assign self.y in get_context_data and access the variable in post method like x = self.y . But am getting the attribute error like 'xxxxx' object has no attribute 'y'

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that `get_context_data` is called *after* `post`. When `post` runs, `y` hasn't been set yet.

You shouldn't be overriding `post` anyway. You haven't stated what you need to do with that variable, but there is certainly a more appropriate method to override.

Also, note that just assigning to `y` inside a method doesn't have any effect outside that method: you need to assign to `self.y`. And the class-level assignment is pointless, you should remove it.